# Email setup in webmin

Tags: email, webmin

I have an email address setup in webmin and when I went to test it I received the email but it was in the form of name@www.domainname.com instead of name@domainname.com. Could someone help me by giving me instructions on how to change this configuration so the www is not part of the email address.

Thank you

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your servers list and click on the DNS tab.  Click on the server that you want to modify and look at the list of items.  If you see one that says CNAME and it has a www.domain.com in it for the name that should be changed to just domain.com

That is if you have a live server and its not just local.